# How can I get a String value for ArrayList library?

Tags: java, arrays, oop

I hope you are having an amazing day.

I was practicing my POO on Java and I trying to make a program in which I register books info and them I calculated the book with the highest page number.

So, I sharing my algorithm with you. When I run this code, I get an error. I reviewed the [ArrayList Library](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) documentation and I was unable to find any solution.

Can you help me out with this guys? I'm a spanish speaker, so variables names are on my language. I sorry for that, but I pretty sure that you can understand it.

```
public static void registrarLibros() {
    
    int cantidadLibros, numPag;
    String ISBN, Titulo, Autor;
    
    System.out.print("Ingrese la cantidad de libros a registrar: ");
    cantidadLibros = scan.nextInt();
    
    for (int i=0; i>cantidadLibros; i++) {
        System.out.print("ISBN del libro " + i + ": ");
        ISBN = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Titulo del libro " + i + ": ");
        Titulo = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Autor del libro " + i + ": ");
        Autor = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Cantidad de paginas del libro " + i + ": ");
        numPag = scan.nextInt();
        
        Libro libro = new Libro(ISBN, Titulo, Autor, numPag) {};
        libros.add(libro);
    }
    
}

public static void mostrarDatos() {
    for (Libro l: libros) {
        System.out.println(l.toString());
    }
}

public static void libroMayorPaginas() {
    int maxPag = 0;
    String maxTitulo;
    for (Libro l: libros) 
    {
        if (maxPag<l.getNumeroPaginas()) 
            {
            maxPag = l.getNumeroPaginas();
            maxTitulo = l.getAutor();
            }
    }
    System.out.print("El libro con mayor cantidad de paginas es " + maxTitulo + " con " + maxPag + " paginas.");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Registrar libros
    registrarLibros();
    
    //Mostrar datos
    mostrarDatos();
    
    //Calcular el libro con mayor cantidad de paginas
    libroMayorPaginas();
}
```

}

Comment: Can you share the error you are getting

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Kleo. I'm still learning the basics but I will addressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the registrar libros method.I think the for loop should be
`for(int i=0;i<cantidadLibros;i++)`.But you have put the condition as `i>catidadLibros` with i++ increment.so if i is already greater than catidadLibros it will become a endless loop or if it is lesser than,the for loop will not be executed

Comment: Thank youuuuu. Now runs perfectly, it was just a simple error haha.